# Should I use @Autowired annotation in java test classes?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, junit5

I have always used @Mock and @injectMock in java test classes. I came in a weird situation today. When I do @mock for WebTestClient then it gives me null pointer exception saying that it has a possibility to be null.

And when I change the annotation to @Autowire, it works as expected.

Pls let me know why is @mock not working in above case. I apologize if the question is really stupid to ask here.

I am trying to test a controller that returns Flux<Integer>.

Also pls answer this for me:

- Is it a good practice to use @Autowired in test classes or we only use it in special cases?

I was expecting using mock should not give me NPE.

Comment: Please add some example code for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have are writing a test that is starting the spring context (for example, the one annotated with `@SpringBootTest`), you'll be able to @Autowire beans from the context. This will give you actual (real) objects.

On the other hand, mocks are 'fake' objects that look like real ones, but they do nothing - if you don't specify a clear behavior, they just return null.

So, when you mocked your WebClient, a code like this might throw an exception:

```java
webClient.get()
  .uri("/api/users/123")
  .exchange()
  ...etc
```

That's because WebClient is using this fluent API which might be harder to mock. The return of the `.get()` will be null and therefore, the `.uri(...)` will throw an exception.

---

So, they provided some alternatives for mocking. As you mentioned in the question, there is this `WebTestClient`,  an object which follows the same interface but it's created specifically for unit testing. Since you ae already using this WebTestClient, there is no point in trying to mock it:  being a test object, it will not perform the actual HTTP call.